# NestJS and JWT authorizaion problem. Error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, nestjs

I am building a fullstack web app which is basically ecommerce shop. The idea is to GET a cart or order of a user if he already have some in database. Projec is build with React, NestJS, TypeOrm and MySQL.

The problem is that I can't make Jwt authorization to work. I can only log in. If I add @UseGuard to the endpoint I always get error "401 (Unauthorized)". I have been checking documentation and online tutorials and I still can't figure out what is wrong.

Link to a repo https://github.com/Jacob120/e-commerce-fullstack-app

**auth.controller.ts**

```
import {
  Controller,
  Request,
  Post,
  UseGuards,
  Body,
  Get,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from 'src/auth/service/auth.service';
import { HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtAuthGuard } from 'src/auth/guards/jwt-auth.guard';
import { Users } from 'src/auth/user.entity';

@Controller('api/auth/')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private usersService: AuthService) {}

  @Post('signup')
  async signup(@Body() user: Users): Promise<Users> {
    const checkUsername = await this.usersService.findOne(user.username);

    if (checkUsername) {
      throw new HttpException(
        'Username already exists',
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      );
    }
    return this.usersService.signup(user);
  }

  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  @Post('login')
  async login(@Request() req) {
    return this.usersService.login(req.user);
  }

  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @Get('profile')
  getProfile(@Request() req) {
    return req.user;
  }
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Users } from '../user.entity';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Users) private userRepository: Repository<Users>,
    private jwt: JwtService,
  ) {}

  async signup(user: Users): Promise<Users> {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
    user.password = hash;

    user.role = 'user';
    return await this.userRepository.save(user);
  }

  async validateUser(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const foundUser = await this.userRepository.findOneBy({ username });

    if (foundUser) {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, foundUser.password)) {
        const { password, ...result } = foundUser;
        return result;
      }

      return null;
    }
    return null;
  }
  async login(user: any) {
    const payload = { username: user.username, sub: user.id, role: user.role };

    return {
      access_token: this.jwt.sign(payload),
      role: user.role,
      username: user.username,
    };
  }

  async findOne(username: string): Promise<Users | undefined> {
    return await this.userRepository.findOne({
      where: { username },
    });
  }
}
```

**auth.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { jwtConstants } from './guards/constants';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AuthService } from './service/auth.service';
import { JwtStrategy } from './guards/jwt-strategy';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';
import { AuthController } from './controller/auth/auth.controller';
import { Users } from './user.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: jwtConstants.secret,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '1d' },
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Users]),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy, LocalStrategy],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [AuthService, PassportModule],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

**jw-auth.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {}
```

**jwt-strategy.ts**

```
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { jwtConstants } from './constants';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: jwtConstants.secret,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return {
      userId: payload.sub,
      username: payload.username,
      role: payload.role,
    };
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I have changed jwt-auth.guard a little bit and `console.log(info)` in `handleRequest(err, user, info)` is throwing back "Error: No auth token"

```
import {
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    // Add your custom authentication logic here
    // for example, call super.logIn(request) to establish a session.
    return super.canActivate(context);
  }

  handleRequest(err, user, info) {
    console.log(info);
    if (err || !user) {
      throw err || new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you take a trace with your browser to check that the access token is given to the client just after authentication?

Comment: Well in my Login,js file i fetch data which respond with access_token, username and role. I save it in sessionStorage.setItem('token'). I'm not sure if this is what you are asking about?

Comment: I've added new details under EDIT in my main post.

Answer (score 0):

> `Error: No auth token`

This means that your client is not sending a request that has an `Authorization` header in the form of `Bearer <jwt>`, so passport can't validate the token

Comment: hmm any tips on how should I fix that?